# Use svn programmatically from eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin

I need to get an SVN status and invoke an SVN commit from an eclipse plugin (and probably also create a tag).

One way to solve the problem would be to use Runtime to call svn through the command line (and parse the result). Maybe it is also possible to use subclipse or one of its libraries to do the job more directly, but this is not clear to me how that could be done.

I want to avoid adding additional Java libraries that are not already part of eclipse or subclipse.

Comment: May be you would like to have a look at the eclipse team support http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fteam.htm

Comment: Thank you, @saurav, but it is not clear to me how to actually use the Team Support in the context of SVN.